# solr not writing logs when it runs not from its main folder

Tags: solr, solr4

When I run solr using

```
java -jar "C:\solr\example\start.jar"
```

It writes logs to C:\solr\example\logs.

When I run it using

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home="C:\solr\example\solr" 
     -Djetty.home="C:\solr\example" 
     -Djetty.logs="C:\solr\example\logs" 
     -jar "C:\solr\example\
```

start.jar"

it writes logs only if I run it from

C:\solr\example>

any other folder - logs are not written.
This is important as I need to run it as a service later (using nssm)
What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the Jetty-hosted example distributed with Solr must be started in the example directory to function properly. Try creating a batch file that changes to the directory then invokes Java, like this:

```
C:
cd C:\solr\example\
java -Dsolr.solr.home="C:\solr\example\solr" 
     -Djetty.home="C:\solr\example" 
     -Djetty.logs="C:\solr\example\logs" 
     -jar "C:\solr\example\
```

Then have NSSM run the batch file instead of java.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers should work for you.

You could set it up using apache Tomcat as opposed to the Jetty instance Solr comes with.  Tomcat which comes standard with a startup.bat batch file that you use to start your server